# Why does the "Assert" class have so many seemingly redundant methods? When should each be used?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, assert

So I see that Assert has dozens of methods that seem to do essentially the same thing.

```
Assert.IsFalse(     a == b );
Assert.IsTrue(      a != b );
Assert.AreNotEqual( a,   b );
```

Why? Is it just to be more explicit? When should the various methods be used? Is there an offical best practices document?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference between `IsFalse` and `IsTrue` is readability. `AreNotEqual` allows a better error message to be presented when the test fails. `IsTrue` for example will just tell you that the answer was supposed to be true and was really false. `AreNotEqual` will show the two values that were compared in its error message.

Comment: IMO, this is the best/most concise answer I've seen so far. Top answer is missing that it gives a more informative error message.

Comment: Fluent assertion frameworks are increasing in popularity precisely because they increase readability. See, for example, JUNit's Hamcrest matchers (http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial) and NUnit's ConstraintModel (http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=constraintModel&r=2.4.1).

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: For readability.

Slightly longer answer:

Your tests are also code, and in terms of intent are as important as the code you are testing. As such, you want to make the intent of the test as clear as possible. Sometimes that means you use `IsFalse`, sometimes it means using `IsTrue`.

Comment: "You[r] tests are also code... you want to make the intent of the test as clear as possible"

...to play devils advocate: Then why isn't it standard practice to create and use isEqual, isNotEqual, etc in normal code? (I'm aware that Equals exists, but it's less commonly used)

Comment: @Catskul: Testing is all about maintainability.  We do use == and != for equality and inequality in regular code.  How often do you see: "if (a == (!b) )" instead of "if (a != b)"?

Comment: @Reed, "!b" may not have any sense. Asserts AFAIK must always reduce to true/false.

Comment: @Catskul: ...but when it does make sense, would you write it that way?  Of course not - you'd use the appropriate != method instead.

Comment: @Catskul: If you don't like that case - how often do you write:  "if (!(a == b))" instead of "if (a != b)"?  There's a reason we use the separate methods in the language...

Comment: @Reed, but again playing devils advocate: If it's true that "AreNotEqual" is clearer, then why shouldn't we be using it in all of our code rather than just in unit tests?

Answer (score 4):

Those three methods have three different, specific goals.  The goal of testing is to provide clear verification and validation of your code.  By using the most clear and specific method possible, you're making your test the smallest test possible, with the most specific, clear meaning possible.

This helps because it adds clarity - you can see, specifically, what a test is supposed to do in a more declarative nature, where using the same method for multiple testing scenarios, which each have a different meaning, requires more understanding of the code itself, instead of the nature of the test.

In this case, the third is the (only) appropriate one to use.  However, if you had this situation, you'd use a different one, for example:

```
Assert.IsTrue( myClass.MethodThatReturnsTrue() );
```

You should use the method that provides the most clarity as to your goal - if you're checking two values for equality, use `Assert.IsEqual`, if you're checking a boolean to verify that it's false, use `Assert.IsFalse`.  This makes the error reports meaningful and understandable.

Comment: You've asserted(no pun intended) that they do very different things, but haven't offered an explanation.

Comment: @Catskul: I reworded - does that help?

Answer (score 1):

It makes the errors easiest to read; use the one that matches your code most closely.

In this case, use #3.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can overload the == and != , thats why.

Comment: ... and you can write your own Equals method. AFAIK it's not clear that these Assert methods don't themselves rely on those operators or the Equals method for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a "Fluent Interface"... and makes things more readable in the opinion of many.